# xpath expression wild-cards

Tags: xpath, wildcard

I have a requirement to specify wild card in the following xpath

```
Field[@name="/Root/Table[i]/FirstName"]
```

Basically the "i" would be a variable which can have either a GUID or a running number. I would like to pick up all elements that basically have the attribute pattern

```
"/Root/Table[*]/FirstName"
```

i.e. starting with "/Root/Table[" and ending with "]/FirstName". Any ideas as to how this can be done ?

Here is a sample payload:

```
<Package>
  <Input>
    <Data id="36e9f0fe3f8d4508ac20710e07cfddd4">
      <Input>
        <Field name="/Root/Table[1]/FirstName">Thomas</Field>
      </Input>
    </Data>
  </Input>
</Package>
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of what the XML looks like? It's not really clear what you're asking.

Comment: Have added a sample payload to the question. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this using `starts-with()` and a makeshift `ends-with()` (since XPath 1.0 doesn't actually have an `ends-with()` function):

```
//*[starts-with(@name, '/Root/Table[') and 
    substring(@name, string-length(@name) - 11 + 1) = ']/FirstName']
```

Here, `11` is the length of `]/FirstName`.